# How to use URL-based AJAX in Drupal 7 to serve all pages?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, uri

I know this can be done through jQuery alone, but I'm interested in knowing if there any Drupal 7 ways of achieving this:

I want to use AJAX to serve all non-admin pages on my site. Also I don't want it to just replace parts of a page, but load entire pages over AJAX. The [AJAX Framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax) allows loading partial contents over AJAX based on various triggers. But I want to make a URL based navigation system.

Here are the things I want to accomplish:

- Redirect http://example.com/node/1 to http://example.com/#!/node/1. So search engines can index the node normally.
- Drupal reads the string from URL (node/1) and fetches the relevant string in json format.
- Insert the resulting data into page and replace existing content.
- Refreshes blocks that should appear on the corresponding page.
- Refreshes title in browser (optional).
- Needs to work with Panels.

If I create a new module, what functions and/or frameworks in Drupal can I use to make this work?

Thanks.

-Kaustav

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this and currently stuck that content that's being loaded by JS is not being processed by the relevant JS code. Creating a new question for this particular issue...

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37436/how-to-re-run-javascript-core-code-for-content-loaded-with-jquerys-ajax

Comment: The main problem: http://drupal.org/node/1703356

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching also a solution to do that. I would like to allow users to choose witch content type is displaying in a region.

I started by create one block by region and inside I put different functions like the following one to get different content.

```
node_view_multiple(array($node->nid => $node), $display_type); // To get a node.
module_invoke($module, 'block_view',$delta); // To get a block.
panels_mini_block_view($minipanel_name); // To get a mini panel.
```

Now, with the CSS ID of the block, I will try to refresh them using AJAX link.
I think I will have to override all the links of Drupal to somethings like main/nojs/#div_region_id/[drupal-url] (e.g. main/nojs/block-content/node/1) and add them a `class="use-ajax"`.

The management what is refresh will be in `ajax_callback_response()`.

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_html('#block-content', $output );
$page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($page);
```

Another way may be also with the [Content page](http://drupal.org/project/content_page) module.

Comment: Thanks @jonathan. My aim is similar to what the [Asynchronous](http://drupal.org/project/asynchronous) module does for Drupal 6, i.e., rewrite all drupal links on the fly and pull in data from Drupal through JSON.

Comment: The [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module can also be an option. I have not tried it though.