# How to use pjax module for batrik theme content?

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes

I am trying to use [pjax](https://drupal.org/project/pjax) module for content part reloading without refreshing a page but i following the instruction form pjax read me part but not worked. How to configure the module for batrik theme content part. please help me.

Comment: have you tried any of this methods https://drupal.org/node/1846300

Comment: @Bala Yes I tried but not worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the module is not maintained and importantly the module is still in unstable state.

So you shouldn't be relying on this module, unless you're ready to make it stable.

You can check the alternatives here,

[How to use URL-based AJAX in Drupal 7 to serve all pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14344/how-to-use-url-based-ajax-in-drupal-7-to-serve-all-pages)

But AFAIK there is no module available as of now with the same feature.